# Problem with installing ubuntu on Windows 8

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-8, live-usb

So I have set up the Ubuntu installer by installing it onto my memory stick using the USBInstaller.

I am then faced with a problem. The Ubuntu Installer loads up and I start going through it making the relevant choices.

I then select 'Install Ubuntu with Windows 8', or whatever the option is, as I still want both operating systems.

However, when I click continue, my computer restarts. This therefore means that the installer is loaded again from the USB, it then tries to install again, which means I get to the save position before BAM, it restarts again.

If it restarts and I remove the memory stick, then Windows 8 loads.

I really have no idea what to do? My computer appears to be acting as it should really, I  just don't understand why I have to restart before installing?

Comment: Try creating your live-USB via another software. eg UnetBootIn or LiliUSB.

Answer (score 1):

first I would [check your iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) and make the USB again to make sure your installation USB is correct.

Comment: I've downloaded the iso a couple of times and I've installed it to the USB 4 times. However my problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a full system backup on your Windows system before attempting anything else on the install.  One easy way to do this is to go to Start, Run, and choose 'Backup & Restore' (if you start typing the command, it will autocomplete).

Once your system is backed up, run CrystalDiskInfo (open source), as mentioned in http://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/.  This won't diagnose 100% of disk problems, but it can at least give you an idea.  I would also recommend selecting memtest86 during Ubuntu bootup, as mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FaultyHardware.  That link has some other resources, but you may find CrystalDiskInfo to provide more data.  Choosing to 'try Ubuntu without installing' (LiveCD mode) definitely gives you access to a ton of open source utilities to help you diagnose any hardware issues.

There are a lot of other considerations for running Windows 8 and Ubuntu simultaneously.  Since it can be hairy for an experienced user, I definitely recommend backing up your Windows data as rule for dual-boot installs (I sure do).

Comment: CrystalDiskInfo said my hard drive is 'good'. I'm not sure if there is any problem with the system itself but I guess what is happening to me shouldn't be?